# LPC2148 assembly code. Trying to read data from read-write memory but Label showing blank data

Tags: arm, embedded

I am trying to copy data from LUT from one location and copying it to another location. Here is the code

```
    AREA    Program, CODE, READONLY
    EXPORT __main
    ENTRY

__main
    ldr     r0, =SourceL        ; Address of SourceL
    ldr     r1, =DestinationL   ; Address of DestinationL
    ldr     r2, [r0]            ; r2 contains data@SourceL
    str     r3, [r1]            ; r3 contains data@DestinationL
    
    mov     r4, #245
    str     r4, [r1]
    
    SWI     &11
    
    AREA MyData, DATA, READWRITE

SourceL
    DCW     &1234
    ALIGN

DestinationL
    DCW     &0
    ALIGN

    END
```

This is a very basic ARM7TDMI assembly code.
When I see the address of Labels(in debugger). SourceL is `0x40000000` and DestinationL is `0x40000004`.

But when I see the memory locations, they are having zero values .

But in LUT SourceL is having value `&1234`.

When I try to store some data at memory representing by label DestinationL I am able to successfully do that.

This is not the only case of this above code.

The example code in the ARM website

```
      AREA    StrCopy, CODE, READONLY
      EXPORT    __main
      ENTRY                             ; Mark first instruction to execute
    
__main
    LDR     r1, =srcstr               ; Pointer to first string
    LDR     r0, =dststr               ; Pointer to second string
    
    BL      strcopy                   ; Call subroutine to do copy
stop
    MOV     r0, #0x18                 ; angel_SWIreason_ReportException
    LDR     r1, =0x20026              ; ADP_Stopped_ApplicationExit
    SVC     #0x123456                 ; ARM semihosting (formerly SWI)
    
strcopy
    LDRB    r2, [r1],#1               ; Load byte and update address
    STRB    r2, [r0],#1               ; Store byte and update address
    CMP     r2, #0                    ; Check for zero terminator
    BNE     strcopy                   ; Keep going if not
    MOV     pc,lr                     ; Return
    
    AREA    Strings, DATA, READWRITE
 srcstr  DCB     "First string - source",0
 dststr  DCB     "Second string - destination",0
    END
```

The memory corresponding to srcstr is showing zero only.

I am using KEIL IDE for programming.

Why data in LUT is not shown in the memory location?

Thanks!

Comment: Any answer please

Comment: The code does exactly what the comments say - which does not include copying @Source: to DestinationL, so why are you surprised?  Is this your own code?

Comment: You state: _"the memory locations, they are having values zero.",  and : _"in LUT SourceL is having value &1234."_.  Both statements cannot be true.

Comment: I am not bothered about why data hasn't been copied. My concerned is in the memory location of SourceL, why there is not data. When I am initializing RAM location of SourceL with &1234, then RAM memory should show, but it is showing zero.

Comment: then you need to ask a different question, because this one is exactly about why the data was not copied.  And changing the question after it had a reasonable answer was bad form; it has rendered nonsense an answer given in good faith.

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not copy `@SourceL` to `@DestinationL`.  It only loads data into registers and does nothing with it (exactly per the comments).

```
ldr     r0, =SourceL        ; Address of SourceL
ldr     r1, =DestinationL   ; Address of DestinationL
ldr     r2, [r0]            ; r2 contains data@SourceL
str     r2, [r1]            ; Copy data@SourceL to DestinationL  <<ADD THIS
```

Comment: Forget about my code. I have given the example code from ARM website also below my code. It tried to copy one string to another memory location. Logic is same. But again the question is @srcstr  when you the RAM memory it is zero, no string.

Comment: thanks for pointing my mistake. But even after this change. The data is not copied, as SourceL RAM location doesn't have any data. So where this &1234 has gone. If I want SourceL RAM location to be filled with &1234, what needs to be done? I don't want the data to be in ROM, I wanted to copy the data from one RAM location to another.

Comment: There needs to be some linked start-up code that copies the initialisation data from ROM into the RAM location before __main is invoked.

Comment: But MyData or Strings are defined under READWRITE, i.e. RAM location. This wont be in ROM, If I am understanding it correct. So how ROM to RAM copying will help? This code is very basic code in every tutorial but nothing is helping to get the desired result. Please guide me and if you can spare some time and try this code!!!

Comment: @user9603264 Think about it... The assembler/linker cannot magically assign the RAM. The initial data is contained in the ROM image, and must be copied to RAM on start-up.  That too does not happen by magic.  There must be code to initialise the RAM.  Often your development tool will provide this code for you, and it must be linked to your code.  In some cases, this initialisation can be disabled.

Comment: Yes you are right! But as I can see the RAM location is 0x40000000. When the code is in ROM, what could be the address? Sorry I am really confused, my questions may look stupid!

Comment: I am using KEIL. Are you using GNU ARM? If you can try this small code on your IDE with modifications, please give it here. I will change and use to KEIL. I don't meant for spoon feeding but there is no help I am getting.

Comment: @user9603264 : The link map will show you that.  You should not need to know, there should be standard start-up initialisation code running before __main.  This is no longer a question about your code (it never was), it is about your project setup and configuration.  You should perhaps start again with a new question.  In Keil uVision, when you start a new project, and select a part, it will offer to add start-up code to your project.  If you selected a generic target, rather than LPC2148, it will not have been able to do that

Comment: I have installed KEIL version 4 and also version 5. I had tried both and used intial LPC2148 startup file. But the code is not working anyway!. The startup file is very big and so cant post it here!

Comment: Is there any one who can tell me what to do? I even tried to install GNU ECLIPSE ARM, but there is no support for LPC2148. In KEIL there is seperate legacy application for old ARM7TDMI. But here in GNU I didn't find anything. Guide me if any one can. I have tried many ways as per google search from last 2 days, nothing worked!!!

Comment: @user9603264 : your problem getting the start-up code working is an entirely different question.  SO is not a discussion forum, your _new_ problem cannot be resolved using comments on an entirely different question.

Comment: I have seen all the source code from GITHUB for LPC2148. The startup code there is same as what I am using. There is no single line of code difference in that. It means the startup code is valid generated by KEIL. If any one has faced this issue, then could any one provide me the startup file. Even if it belongs to GNU please give me. If this forum can't help then tell me on which forum should I ask?

Comment: @user9603264 : You are not listening!  So is not a forum.  You can ask your question here, but you have to ask an independent question, not discuss it in the comments to an answer to a different question.  SO is Q&A, not a discussion forum.

Comment: @user9603264 : Bear in mind when you ask that question, that code works for thousands of existing developers, so you have to provide sufficient detail about what is happening and what you have done for anyone to have a chance of determining why I'd does not work for you.  I'd start by stepping the code to see where it fails, or if it even starts.